# Alguien sabe que significa esto?

Tags: javascript, php, backend

Estoy haciendo un formulario de contacto para una pagina web, validada con javascript, y mandando los datos a un correo con php. Por alguna razon el correo en blanco y se envia al cargar la pagina, no al dar click en el boton enviar. Pero el problema fundamental es que al final de la pagina me sale el siguiente mensaje:

`Notice: Undefined index: name in /storage/ssd3/058/18471058/public_html/validation.php`

Comment: Sin ver tu código solo podemos hacer suposiciones. La mía es que intentas tomar los datos antes de que hayan sido enviados. Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar el código.

Comment: Revisa lo que te dice el comentario de Triby y ve a [edit] tu pregunta, añade la info faltante para que puedan ayudarte rápidamente

Comment: que en validation.php estás intentando acceder a `algo[name]`, el cual no existe ni está definido.